# SharePoint Designer 2013 - External Content Type, Page Number filter issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

I have created an `External Content Type` using SharePoint Designer. The data source is SQL table. The data in SQL table may increase up to around 25k rows.

To handle this situation, we are using Page Number filter to enable the users to view all items by modifying the views.

The problem is that as soon as I add Page Number type filter in the External Content Type, it disappears from External Content Type picker while creating list.

If I try to create list from SharePoint designer, I get an error `Could not save changes`.

I couldn't find any documentation about using Page Number Filter, does it require any additional configuration? Please suggest.

The External Content Type has Read List, Read Item and Update operations.

Lokesh

Comment: Try clearing SharePoint Designer Cache.

Comment: This doesn't help. The external content type disappears from ECT picker while creating a new list in SharePoint site as soon as I add Page Number type filter. Seems the issue is with adding this filter.

Comment: I tried regenerating your scenario and it got regenerated. Also, found below line in logs "Finder '<READ LIST>' has a filter of type 'PageNumber'. These filters are not supported for external lists.Creating no view for this finder." As a result, no view is generated. Hence, while creating a list, you do not get this ECT listed and in SPD, it throws error.

Comment: Could you please make sure if Parameters in Read List and Read Item operation are same?